# Find $f(1)$ given the following ($f$ polynomial)

Tags: calculus

Suppose 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{2x^2 + x +1} = 1, \qquad 
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x)}{x^2-x-2} = 3
$$
Then find $f(1)$.

What kind of method should I take?

Comment: For the second limit, decompose the denominator into linear factors using the p-q-formula. The first limit does not define f(1) uniquely.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** First note that $f$ must have degree $2$ because ... So $f(x) =ax^2 + bx + c$. You want to find $f(1) = a + b + c$.

The first limit will allow you to find $a$ and the second limit will allow you to find $b$ and $c$.
So, for example,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ax^2 + bx + c}{2x^2 +x +1} = ... = 1
$$
For the second limit, note that $2$ must be a zero of $f$, because ..., so now factor ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the limits for both parts:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{2x^2+x+1} = 1 \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{f(x)}{x^2}}{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} = 1 \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 2$$

Which yells that $f(x) = 2x^2+ax+b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

For the second part: 
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^2-x-2} = 3$$

As you can see, the denominator is $0$ when $x = 2$ which means that $f(x)$  has to be factorizable by $(x-2)$, so it has to be something like $f(x) = (x-2)(2x+n) = 2x^2+(n-4)x-2n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{R}$, so if we replace with this at the second limit

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^2-x-2} = \lim_{x \to 2} \dfrac{(x-2)(2x+n)}{x^2-x-2} =  \lim_{x \to 2} \dfrac{(2x+n)}{x+1} = \dfrac{4+n}{3} = 3 \implies n = 5$$

so $f(x)= (x-2)(2x+5) \implies f(1)= (-1)(7)= -7$

Comment: That last line should be $4 + n = 9 \Rightarrow n = 5$

Comment: Also that should be $+5$